# How can I write a single for loop running from a to z and A to Z in C?

Tags: c

I want to combine both the for loops into single for loop. How can i do that?

I want to loop through a to z, and A to Z, like so:

```
char ch;
for (ch = 'A' ; ch <= 'Z' ; ch++ )
{ 
}
for (ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch++ )
{
}
```

but using a single loop.

Comment: If you want it in C, why is the question also tagged C++?

Comment: ... and the point of this is?

Comment: @Ted hopp , sorry i removed c++ , that was by mistake.

Comment: @misha , was majorly programming in web side , suddenly i need a program in c to get the no of occurences of a character in a string , i though of loop through all a to z and A to Z and match and print the count...

Comment: @kobe: Then you should use `isalpha` instead of doing this yourself.

Comment: @kobe If what you want to do is determine whether some character matches [A-Z][a-z], looping over them is a horrid way to do it. Billy is right -- use isalpha, which looks the character up in a table.

Comment: @jim , i will look at that and give a try.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't personally *like* this solution, but:

```
char * letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (char * ptr = letters; *ptr != 0; ++ptr) {
    char ch = *ptr;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @myrkos `ptr` won't, but `*ptr` will. Otherwise `strlen(letters)` wouldn't work.

Comment: 1. +1. 2. Fixed that the OP's code does capital letters first. 3. Expanded the whole alphabet string.

Comment: That was my clever Jedi mind trick to get you do all that typing for me :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't actually prefer this approach to Billys.  It's less readable (would you notice a missing character in a magic string like that, or notice if the order where unusual?), it's probably slower, and it isn't even any shorter.  Not that it really matters in such a simple case...

Comment: @Eamon: Shhh, if you get rid of code like that, where will we hide all our backdoors?!

Comment: I too dislike this solution (mainly for the reasons Eamon pointed out) but if you care about it being completely portable and agnostic to character encoding, I think it's just about the only correct solution. If you're happy to assume ASCII-based encoding, use one of the other answers.

Comment: Besides the character-set-blindness, the other small advantage here is it generalizes to other character subsets. Want to add numbers too? No problem. Just lower case letters plus underscore? Just do it. Only consonants? Have at it.

Comment: Yeah, context matters.  Perhaps you need it, perhaps you don't.  If you don't - the extra flexibility is only a source of bugs.

Answer (score 24):

```
for (char ch = 'A' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch == 'Z' ? ch = 'a' : ++ch )
{
}
```

Should work -- though please, please, don't inflict this on your fellow developers.

Comment: @Bo: Did the OP's original code work on the machine you're on? ('cause if this code does not work, the OP's didn't work either)

Comment: @Billy - No, of course I'm on an IBM mainframe. My comment was targeted at @Eamon's "simple, works". Ernest's solution **does** work, and I can even add the åäö I need for my native language. :-)

Comment: @Bo: But the OP asked for A-Za-z -- This code fits the spec. (What, you're changing requirements on me now? :P )

Comment: @Billy: If the system's native encoding is an EBCDIC variant, the letters (of a single case) are not mapped to a contiguous range of numbers.

Comment: @Donal: I understand that. However, working on such systems was not part of the spec. The OP's code does not work there; merging the OP's two loops therefore does not have to either. The spec was "merge these two loops", not "write a single loop that goes over all letter characters".

Comment: Or to put it another way - the OP says the loop runs from `A` to `Z`, not that the values in between `A` and `Z` are all Roman uppercase letters :-) So it does "work" on EBCDIC too, it just enumerates a different set of `char` values, some of which aren't character code points at all. Inadequate specifications can *always* be weaseled to say whatever it is the code actually does. Goes wrong if `'z' < 'A'`, mind, but unless Bo whips up a quick C implementation using a charset that he invents today, that's not the case on the machine he's on.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a nested loop (two loops, but only one body):

```
for (start = 'A'; start <= 'a'; start += 'a' - 'A') {
    end = start + 'Z' - 'A';
    for (ch = start; ch <= end; ++ch) {
         /* body */
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for what looks like the most mind-bendingly-evil answer here.

Comment: @Billy Mua-ha-ha! (and thanks!) Code maintenance folk need a challenge now and then. :-)

Comment: I suggest instead

    `char start = 'A';
    do{
        char end = start + 'Z' - 'A';
        char ch;
        for (ch = start; ch <= end; ++ch) {
             /* body */
        }
    }while((start = 'A' + 'a' - start) == 'a');`

which has no ASCII dependency.

Comment: @Jim: that still has the dependancy that a..z are consecutive; and it's not like ASCII/unicode is going anywhere...

Comment: @Eamon Ah yes, I forgot that a..z aren't consecutive in EBCDIC (and I grew up on an 026 card punch). As for ASCII/unicode not going anywhere, that's beside the point ... other coding systems do exist, and are used, and strict conformance to the C standard is often an issue here at SO/[c], even when something works in all C systems that one might reasonably encounter.

Comment: But the goal is to reproduce OP's original looping behavior, not hit every letter and only letters. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the obvious question is why? ...and the second question is do you care about non-ASCII character sets (as your two loops will fail for EBCDIC), but the quick and dirty way of connecting the two is

```
for (ch = 'A'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    if (ch > 'Z' && ch < 'a') ch = 'a';
     :
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing I did except I used the question mark operator. +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char diff = 'a' - 'A';
for (ch = 'A' ; ch <= 'Z' ; ch++ )
{
  char small_ch = ch + diff;
 //... 
}
```

Comment: This iterates in a different order than the OP's original code.

Comment: @Billy, the idea is to combine the contents of both the loops, for caps use `ch` and for small, use `small_ch`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, strictly speaking, the OP's code iterates as "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", while this example will iterate as "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz". If the order would matter the result would be different.

Comment: I think this misses the point. If you're going to repeat the logic, once for ch and once for small_ch, you might as well have to loops. What is wanted is for the single variable ch to iterate over A .. Z a .. z and to apply some logic to it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
            printf("%c\n", 'A' + i + ('a' - 'Z' - 1) * (i/26));
```

Comment: Replacing `6` with `('a' - 'Z')` would remove the ASCII dependency.

Comment: Eamon Nerbonne points out that the mere fact that 'a' .. 'z' are contiguous is an ASCII dependency ... only Ernest Friedman-Hill's answer avoids that. (Still, `('a' - 'Z')` is less obscure than `6`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<26;++i) {

     char ch = 'A' + i;
     // Logic for Uppercase letters.

     char ch1 = 'a' + i;
     // Logic for Lowercase letters.

}
```

Comment: This iterates in a different order than the OP's answer.

Comment: @Billy ONeal Ya, but to print the character count, this would suffice I guess.

Comment: Um, I think the whole point is to avoid duplicating the logic, which is presumably the same for all characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char e;
    for(i=65;i<=122;i++)
    {
                        if(i<91||i>96)
                        {
                            e=i;
                        printf("%c\n",e);
                        }
                        }

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution is

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
  char ch = i + (i < 26? 'A' : 'a');
  /* do something with ch */
}
```

although I prefer, especially in sensible languages that allow nested functions,

```
for(ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
  dosomething(ch);
for(ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
  dosomething(ch);
```

P.S. Kobe, I see in one of your comments that your reason for the loops is to check whether a character is a letter ... but looping is a horrid way to do that. You could simply do

```
if(('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')){
    /* c is a letter */
}
```

or, considerably better,

```
#include ctype.h
...
if(isalpha((unsigned char)c)){
    /* c is a letter */
}
```

(To understand why that cast is needed, read the isalpha man page and the C language standard. This is one of several abominable aspects of C.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'z'; ch = ch == 'Z'?'a':ch+1) {
       //loop body
}
```

This approach is similar to Billy's, but with a slightly less nasty loop-increment statement.  I wouldn't mind inflicting this on a fellow dev, though I might write the increment statement as a function to clarify if the increment statement got any more complex:

```
char nextChar(char c) { return c == 'Z' ? 'a' : c+1; }

for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'z'; ch = nextChar(ch)) {
       //loop body
}
```

Comment: To compare apples to apples, expand `ch++` in Billy's code and you get `ch == 'Z'?ch='a':ch=ch+1`; you've simply factored out the `ch=` and moved it further way from its rhs, which could be considered *more* nasty. As for infliction, neither of these (nor quite a few other answers here) would pass my code review.

Comment: Well, I like my expressions side-effect free; so I much prefer `x = some-side-effect-free-expression` to an if disguised as a ternary.  Such a formulation also lends itself better to function extraction (without worrying about aliasing and whatnot).  Furthermore, the quintessential for-loop is an initialization, a test, and an increment, so the closer to that pattern I can stay, the happier I am -- of course, it's all so trivially short none of this would bother me, but to each their own.  The badness really depends on context.

Answer (score -1):

It's pointless, just use one for loop. The variables are mainly used as counters, or boundaries for the loop so it knows when to terminate. Just make one loop. Two loops are completely unnecessary.

Comment: The loops themselves as written are pointless, because they do nothing ... obviously, the OP intends to put code (the same code twice) inside those loops. The OP is asking how to do it with one loop rather than two. Your "answer" doesn't answer the question, misses the point, and repeats itself three times over. (And I'm not even the downvoter.)

Answer (score -1):

```
void main()
{   
    char ch;

    for(ch= 65 ; ch <= 122 ; ch++)
    {
        if ( ch>=91 && ch<=96)
        continue;                     //hey check this out if this helps
        printf("%c \n",ch);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (ch = 'A';ch <= 'z';ch++) {

}
```

This will also include a few characters such as '[' and ']'...