# Is this correct way to combine std::generate_n and std::back_inserter?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

In my quest :) to use as much of STL as I can I came to wonder is it possible to use std::generate and std::back_inserter combined so that I can do the same thing as the following code :

```
static const size_t nitems=1024*1024;
std::string mrbig;
for (size_t pos=0; pos<nitems; ++pos)
    mrbig.push_back('a'+ (rand()%26));
```

I tried

```
 std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(mrbig),nitems,[](){return 'a'+(rand()%26);});
```

and it seems to work OK, but I would like to be sure Im not messing up something.

Comment: I would add a `mrbig.reserve(nitems);` to avoid reallocations.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work, although you forgot to qualify `std::rand`. Whereas this may still work, it actually shouldn't, at least if you didn't include `stdlib.h` which you should never do in C++.

Comment: @ChristianRau - stdlib.h works just fine in C++.

Comment: There's no need for the outer parentheses in `(rand()%26)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, of course, but this doesn't mean you should use it when there is an actual alternative in the C++ standard library with proper usage of namespaces. Why use a different language when the standard library of your language provides the exact same facilities in a more appropriate way?

Comment: @PeteBecker And well, at least it's deprecated by standard (but Ok, this doesn't need to mean much).

Comment: @ChristianRau - `stdlib.h` is part of standard C++. Its functions are not a separate language. Some of us believe that "proper" use of namespaces includes using the global namespace appropriately.

Comment: @ChristianRau - yes, it's deprecated, the result of anti-C bigotry in the original C++ standard. Even so, it's not going to go away.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well Ok, from the standard it seems you're right, deprecated but definitely part of the C++ standard library, sorry. It may be just my personal opinion that putting things from a library (be it even the standard library) into global namespace is rarely appropriate (nothing against `using`, just not automagically, please). I would still prefer non-deprecated functionality over deprecated functionality and C++ over C/C++, but this may again be subjective (and like said, deprecation doesn't need to mean much). So you got your points.

Comment: @PeteBecker In the end *"anti-C bigotry"* is what keeps the language clean and what keeps us from using *C with classes* or even *C/C++*. Call me a bigot for wanting to program in C++ instead of some strange hybrid unfinished language. But Ok, we're most probably in subjective territory again, but this had to be said.

Comment: it is my fault for not using c++11 <random> :)

Comment: For the sake of anyone wondering what the above discussion is about: `<stdlib.h>` is a C header, which is also part of the C++ standard, but `<cstdlib>` is preferred for C++ since it places the names from `<stdlib.h>` into the `std` namespace. All of the C headers `<foo.h>` have a C++ wrapper `<cfoo>`.

Comment: @boycy - `<stdlib.h>` is a C++ header. The language definition says so. And, yes, some people prefer `<cstdlib>`, but that's a far cry from the subject-less `is preferred`.

Comment: Ooh, should've checked before tapping that out. I was under the impression `<c...>` was the standard-preferred form - thanks for the correction.

Comment: @boycy Even if not the only option, it is indeed standard-preferred, which is the whole meaning of them being *"deprecated"* by standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) requires that its first argument satisfy [`OutputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator), which [`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) does (its `iterator_category` is [`output_iterator_tag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)).

Potential issues with your code:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(mrbig),nitems,[](){return 'a'+(rand()%26);});
```

- Calling `mrbig.reserve(nitems)` would be more efficient.
- You should use [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) `std::rand` or [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)  [`uniform_int_distribution<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) from `<random>` instead of [c](/questions/tagged/c) `rand`.
- The parentheses `()` between the lambda capture and lambda body are unnecessary for a lambda taking no arguments, although some people prefer them.
- It is not guaranteed that in implementation character set the letters `a-z` form a contiguous block; for example, [in EBCDIC, `i` and `j` are not adjacent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Criticism_and_humor).  I believe the only portable form is to store a string `"abcd...xyz"` in your program and index into it: [How can I write a single for loop running from a to z and A to Z in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352870/how-can-i-write-a-single-for-loop-running-from-a-to-z-and-a-to-z-in-c)