# Create a vector with random numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, random

How would I **create** a vector filled with random numbers?

The usual code one finds is along the lines of:

```
std::mt19937 rng {std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist {1, 52};

std::vector<int> vec(10);
std::generate(begin(vec), end(vec), [&]{return dist(rng);} );
```

However this means that each value is touched twice: Once set to zero and then to the random value ([even at O3](https://godbolt.org/z/9teSi7))

So how to do this as efficient as possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12050390/1171191 - although it may be more efficient to just size the `vector` once and then overwrite the values.

Comment: where is anything set to zero?

Comment: Didn't found that question, thanks. I just posted what I deemed to be the answer below as it is 1 solution, although there might be more. (Seen the question afterwards)

Comment: @Pi The ctor does that.

Comment: @Flamefire I meant in the assembly you posted. Cannot find it.

Comment: `xor eax, eax;  rep stosq` in line 325. It stores eax (0) into the address at rdi(?) ecx times (basically the asm of `memset`)

Answer (score 5):

You can make a function call iterator and pass that into vector range constructor:

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>

template<class F, class Tag = std::input_iterator_tag>
class FunctionCallIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade<
          FunctionCallIterator<F, Tag>,
          typename std::result_of<F()>::type,
          Tag,
          typename std::result_of<F()>::type
      >
{
    std::tuple<F, ptrdiff_t> m_; // Enable empty base class optimization for empty F.
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    typename std::result_of<F()>::type dereference() const { return std::get<0>(m_)(); }
    bool equal(FunctionCallIterator const& b) const { return std::get<1>(m_) == std::get<1>(b.m_); }
    void increment() { ++std::get<1>(m_); }
    void decrement() { --std::get<1>(m_); }
    void advance(ptrdiff_t n) { std::get<1>(m_) += n; }
    ptrdiff_t distance_to(FunctionCallIterator const& b) const { return std::get<1>(b.m_) - std::get<1>(m_); }
public:
    FunctionCallIterator(F const& f, ptrdiff_t n) : m_(f, n) {}
};

int main() {
    std::mt19937 rng {std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist {1, 52};
    auto f = [&]{return dist(rng);};
    using RngIter = FunctionCallIterator<decltype(f), std::random_access_iterator_tag>;
    std::vector<int> vec(RngIter{f, 0}, RngIter{f, 10});
    for(auto v : vec)
        std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

Compared to `push_back`/`back_inserter` method this method does not check the current vector size vs its capacity and does not increment vector size for each element.

Comment: This is indeed as efficient as it gets: https://godbolt.org/z/fsoWpY But note that your iterator violates some constraints: It claims to be random-access but isn't. It is rather an input iterator, so usage outside this use case is dangerous. Having a range constructor for vector would be nice (like: `std::vector<int> vec(RandomRange{[&]{return dist(rng);}, 10});`)

Comment: @Flamefire Yes, you are right. It has `random_access_iterator_tag` so that `vector` range constructor allocates once. If it is marked with `input_iterator_tag` the vector constructor does `push_back` method (libstdc++).

Comment: @Flamefire Changed the code to make the user explicitly opt into using `random_access_iterator_tag`, while the default is safe `input_iterator_tag`.

Answer (score 3):

From what I found the combination of `reserve` with `back_inserter` should do the trick:

```
std::mt19937 rng {std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist {1, 52};

std::vector<int> vec;
const size_t size = 1000;
vec.reserve(size);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), size, [&]{return dist(rng);} );
```

This seems to be very efficient but there still is a capacity check, which shouldn't be required: https://godbolt.org/z/sOBlLx

Not sure if `std::vector` allows anything to be more efficient than this. What would be required is an `uninitialized_resize`

Edit: Also seen on [Is this correct way to combine std::generate_n and std::back_inserter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050390/is-this-correct-way-to-combine-stdgenerate-n-and-stdback-inserter)

Comment: Why do you need `back_inserter` for simple `int`? Just `resize` the vector and use `generate` directly. Initialization with zeros is really fast.

Comment: @Evg While it is fast it's still unneeded overhead.  It also doesn't scale well for other types.

Comment: @NathanOliver, for `int` on my machine it is ~2 times faster and for `double` it is ~100 times faster. `std::back_inserter` also has some overhead, and I doubt that it is smaller than zero initialization.

Comment: I've recently heard that the range constructor (the one that takes a pair of iterators) is the fastest way to generate a vector. Though I haven't seen any evidence, it does make sense. It can pre-reserve but also doesn't need to rely on any insertion functions to insert elements, it can insert them directly and can skip the capacity check you mention. You would just need to write a simple input iterator that generates new values on `operator++`. You'd have to get `std::distance` to be constant time for your iterators, which my be a bit trickier in this case.

Comment: @NathanOliver, in the second block you don't need `back_inserter`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've never seen `std::chrono::duration<double>` before. Your code seems to imply that `1.0` is 1 second. How is that?

Comment: Clarification: it is zero-initialization that is ~100 faster for doubles than random filling, not (resize + generate) vs (reserve + generate + back_inserter).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, for `size=100000000` on my machine: reserve+generate+back_inserter - `1.79 s`, resize+generate - `1.79 s`, your approach, vec(rand_it_0, rand_it_1) - `1.74 s`, resize + copy(rand_it_0, rand_it_1, vec.begin()) - `1.81 s`.

Comment: @Evg Did you manage to get a constant time `distance`? If so, what approach did you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180059/discussion-between-francois-andrieux-and-evg).