# Iterate alphabet in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

How do I translate the following code into C/C++?

```
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

foreach(char c in alphabet)
{
    // Do something with the letter
}
```

I want to loop into the alphabet and print each character when a button is pressed. Like how you input a character when using an [Xbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox)/[PS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3) controller. You scroll into the entire set of alphabet and then press a button for input.

Basically this is being used in a microcontroller ([mbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbed_microcontroller)) environment. I just need to know how to create the correct logic in looping in C/C++.

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck ?

Comment: This is C++, sort of.  Definitely not C. "string"

Comment: Any OS/GUI/whatever in particular?  'button'?

Comment: i dont know the equivalent syntax for C++ for looping `foreach`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352870/how-can-i-write-a-single-for-loop-running-from-a-to-z-and-a-to-z-in-c

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void doSomething( const char& );

int main() {
  std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  std::for_each( alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), &doSomething);
}
```

or

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int main() {
  std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  BOOST_FOREACH( char c, alphabet) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

With C++2011

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  std::for_each( alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(),[](const char& c){ /*do something*/} );
}
```

or even

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for( char c : alphabet) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

EDIT:
You mentioned in your edit the desire for this to work in an embedded environment

```
int main() {
  const char* alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for( char* ptr = alphabet; *ptr!='\0'; ++ptr) {
    //do something (*ptr)
  }
}
```

Edit2:

If you *know* that you're using something like ASCII

```
int main() {
  for( char l = 'a'; l<='z'; ++l) {
    //do something (l)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should decide which language you're using; C and C++ are two distinct languages, so there isn't a single answer for both languages.

In modern C++:

```
for (auto c : alphabet)
{
    //do something with letter
}
```

In old-school C++, there are various options; the least ugly is probably

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabet.size(); ++i)
{
    char c = alphabet[i];
    //do something with letter
}
```

In C, it depends what `string` is, since there is no standard type with that name. If it's a conventional zero-terminated character array:

```
char const * alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

then something like:

```
for (char const * p = alphabet; *p; ++p)
{
    char c = *p;
    // do something with letter
}
```

Comment: Using `const char alphabet[] = ..` is a tiny bit more efficient since it avoids a relocation (no separate symbol for the pointer itself) in case this code ends up in a shared library.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
  for ( std::string::iterator itr=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)
  {
  //do something
  }
  return 0;
}
```