# Print values inside the array with an on click event in C++

Tags: c++

Please note that below code is **only the idea**, and **not the actual code**. How do I print the characters inside my `teststring[]` array one at a time when a button is clicked?

```
const string teststring[] = {
                            "a",
                            "b",
                            "c",
                            "d",
                            };


if ( button ).onclick() == true {
    int i = 0;
    printf("output:  %s\r\n", teststring[i]);
    i++;
}
```

It is similar to the code in http://jsfiddle.net/Dfprp/, but this is in JavaScript and instead of numbers, I want the characters that are stored in my `teststring` array.

Comment: That's what editing the question is for. It's very possible to be reopened if edited to a reasonable state.

Comment: is there any reason you're using printf instead of cout?  The question is tagged as "c++" and you're using std::string

Comment: this is code is used on an mbed microcontroller, they use `printf` to print on a terminal

Comment: std::cout prints to the terminal as well... AFAIK

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop?

Comment: @Matthias basically yes, that loops inside an array and prints the value

Comment: That was already answered in your [former question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152136/iterate-alphabet-in-c-c). Maybe, you should read a book to learn C++ syntax.

Comment: Guys/Gals I think he's asking about information on event-based programming. More specifically, since he mentioned and __stresses__ that an action happens on a click. If so, then the OP is asking about GUI based programming in C++. As such, I would suggest getting a book on Qt programming with C++, in addition to C++ books.

Comment: standard C++ does not support events and delegates and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this is what you are looking for

```
std::string teststring = "abcd"

private void myMethod()
{
    int len = teststring.length();
    for(int cnt=0; cnt< len; cnt++)    
        printf("output:  %c\n", teststring[i]);    
}
```